# Setting xlabels for each suplot in a seaborn Pairgrid object plotted using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, subplot

I am trying to set individual xlabels for each subplot in a seaborn parigrid object, but the plot wont update and just shows me the xlables for the bottom most plot only.

```
g = sns.PairGrid(dat,x_vars = inputs, y_vars = outputs, hue = 'variable')

def scatter_plt(x, y, *a, **kw):
    if x.equals(y):
        kw["color"] = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    plt.scatter(x, y,*a, **kw)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)
        
g.map(scatter_plt)
```

I tried the following but it did not work as I saw the same plot as before.

```
xlabels,ylabels = [],[]

for ax in g.axes[-1,:]:
    xlabel = ax.xaxis.get_label_text()
    xlabels.append(xlabel)
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
    ylabel = ax.yaxis.get_label_text()
    ylabels.append(ylabel)

for i in range(len(xlabels)):
    for j in range(len(ylabels)):
        g.axes[j,i].xaxis.set_label_text(xlabels[i])
        g.axes[j,i].yaxis.set_label_text(ylabels[j])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn sets these internal labels invisible, so you explicitly need to set them visible again.

Here is how the code could look like. Some details have also changed:

- Seaborn has some example datasets that can be used for quick testing. Here, the `iris` dataset is used for easy reproducibility.
- `plt.subplots_adjust(...)` only needs to be called once, as it changes the full figure.  Instead of `plt.subplot_adjust()`, `plt.tight_layout()` often works easier, as it tries to optimize all distances.
- Assigning the `xlabels` and `ylabels` via [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) not only makes the code shorter, it also prevents errors and makes things easier to change.
- In a similar reasoning, in Python it's recommended to minimize the use of explicit indices.  That's why often constructions such as `for i, xlabel in enumerate(xlabels)` are seen.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.PairGrid(iris, x_vars=iris.columns[0:4], y_vars=iris.columns[0:3], hue='species')

def scatter_plt(x, y, *a, **kw):
    if not x.equals(y):
        plt.scatter(x, y, *a, **kw)
    plt.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

g.map(scatter_plt)

xlabels = [ax.xaxis.get_label_text() for ax in g.axes[-1, :]]
ylabels = [ax.yaxis.get_label_text() for ax in g.axes[:, 0]]

for i, xlabel in enumerate(xlabels):
    for j, ylabel in enumerate(ylabels):
        g.axes[j, i].set_xlabel(xlabel, visible=True)
        g.axes[j, i].set_ylabel(ylabel, visible=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.PairGrid with internal labels]